# Google Cloud group settings - Authorization failed (python app)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read the users that belons to a google group. I believe the problem is not the application it is some configuration that I could not find. The situation is described as below:

```
- Group: group-tmp
  - created by user user1@company.com
  - members:
    - user1@company.com (owner)
    - group-service@quickstart-...iam... (owner) <-- service user

- Project: quickstart-XXXXX
  - owners:
    - user1@company.com (owner)
    - group-service@quickstart-...iam... (owner)
  - config:
    - api enabled using this website: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/groupssettings.googleapis.com?project=grupo-tmp
```

with the following piece of python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

import json

import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

with open('service_secrets.json') as f:
    json_loaded = json.load(f)

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    json_loaded,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings"])

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('groupssettings', 'v1', http=http)

groups = service.groups()

print('step 4')

g = groups.get(groupUniqueId="group-tmp@company.com").execute()

print('step 5')
```

it always fail between steps 4 and 5 with the following error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/group-tmp@company.com?alt=json returned "Authorization Failed". Details: "Authorization Failed">
```

Comment: 1) You have an authorization error. You have not included information on who owns the group and the identity trying to access that group. 2) Is the service account authorized to access the group? Show those details in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added those information at the beginning of the question

Group `group-tmp` was created by `user1@company.com` and has 2 members (both are owners). I am trying to access with service user (with is one of two owners)

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that when reading your question. Are you using Google Workspace? If not, I do not believe you can access a Google Group with a service account. Do not confuse Google Cloud "Project Owner" outside of Google Cloud. Google Groups is not part of your Google Cloud Project. You can add a Google Group to your project as an "identity" but it is not a resource.